# Fiedler vector of an abstract simplicial complex and partitioning

Tags: graph-theory, hodge-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a connected graph, and $L = A - D$ the corresponding graph Laplacian. The second smallest eigenvalue of $L$, $\lambda_1$, is Fiedler's value, and the associated eigenvector, $\phi_1$, is Fiedler's vector. Fiedler's vector can be used to partition the graph into two regions, well-connected internally but loosely connected between each other, by looking at the sign of the components. The $k$-bottom eigenvector bears a similar meaning and can be used for clustering purposes ([see this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/363923/fiedler-vector-what-else)).

If we generalize this approach by considering an abstract simplicial complex $(V, \Sigma)$ and the combinatorial Hodge Laplacian $L_k$, can we still use the eigenvector associated with the smallest nonzero eigenvector to partition the abstract simplicial complex, and in general the bottom eigenvectors for clustering?